# Count Distinct Visits per user and grouping them

Tags: sql, hadoop, singlestore

SELECT user_id,
SUM(DISTINCT CASE
WHEN click_date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-07-25'
THEN 1 ELSE NULL
END) total_visits_0to8_days,

SUM(DISTINCT CASE
WHEN click_date BETWEEN '2020-07-26' AND  '2020-07-18'
THEN 1 ELSE NULL
END) total_visits_8to14_days,

SUM(DISTINCT CASE
WHEN click_date BETWEEN '2020-07-19' AND  '2020-07-02'
THEN 1 ELSE NULL
END) total_visits_14to30_days,

SUM(DISTINCT CASE
WHEN click_date BETWEEN '2020-07-03' AND  '2020-06-02'
THEN 1 ELSE NULL
END) total_visits_30to60_days,

SUM(DISTINCT CASE
WHEN click_date BETWEEN '2020-06-02' AND  '2020-05-01'
THEN 1 ELSE NULL
END) total_visits_60to90_days

FROM my_table
GROUP BY user_id

My query is returning NULL for all the groups where as I want an aggregate of visit counts per user
DESIRED OUTPUT:

Sum of times each user id visited withing established time windows.

I am using COUNT DISTINCT in order to count each date only once so there should not be in total more than 93 visits per user from May 1st to Aug.1st if that makes sense? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you use `BETWEEN a AND b` you must make sure that `a` is `<=` than `b`, otherwise `BETWEEN` always returns `FALSE` and this is what happens in your code.
So reverse the dates in all cases.
Also use `COUNT()` instead of `SUM()` if you want to count the distinct dates:

```
SELECT user_id, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN click_date BETWEEN '2020-07-25' AND '2020-08-01' THEN click_date END) total_visits_0to8_days,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN click_date BETWEEN '2020-07-18' AND '2020-07-26' THEN click_date END) total_visits_8to14_days,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN click_date BETWEEN '2020-07-02' AND '2020-07-19' THEN click_date END) total_visits_14to30_days,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN click_date BETWEEN '2020-06-02' AND '2020-07-03' THEN click_date END) total_visits_30to60_days,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN click_date BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-06-02' THEN click_date END) total_visits_60to90_days
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: thanks @forpas this definitely fixes my issue, but i am still noticing that there are no 0s in counts meaning per this logic there was always a 1 but when i go and check in the source table there are instances where a click didnt happen during that time and yet i still see a 1

Comment: I can't say why this happens because I don't have your data.

Comment: SUM(DISTINCT...) does not count the distinct dates because out of several distinct dates   it gives 1 as result.

Answer (score 0):

you should use date conversion for'click_date'
is date . for oracle sample below

also notice first variable '2020-07-25' should be less than second '2020-08-01', yours is reverse.

```
click_date BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2020-07-25', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
               AND TO_DATE ('2020-08-01', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```